# Change Netbeans html tag highlight color

Tags: netbeans

Does anyone know where to change the color of the matching tags in Netbeans? Attached is the screenshot to be easier to understand. H3 is highlighted, I want to change that background color.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the *Brace matching (match, multiple characters)* setting is the one you're looking for. As shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: do you know if it's possible to achieve a syntax highlighting in netbeans as it is provided in idea? (differently colored tags depending on nesting depth)

Comment: That's been annoying me for years. Finally did something about it. Thank you.